# ERROR: query has no destination for result data en procedimiento almacenado de pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Cuando intento hacer una consulta almacenada que muestre el nombre del cliente, la provincia y el país al que pertenece un cliente determinado, que se pasará como parámetro, me encuentro con el error de que no me muestra nada:

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data 
HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. 
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function "obtenerDatos"(character varying) line 4 at SQL statement Estado SQL: 42601
```

Tan solo si pido un solo dato es cuando la función se ejecuta:

```sql
begin

SELECT NAME, STATE_ID, COUNTRY_ID FROM RES_PARTNER WHERE NAME = cliente;

end;
```

y me gustaría obtener los datos de las 3 columnas, no solo 1.

Comment: ¿De casualidad estás realizando un procedimiento o una función? Pregunto porque en el título dice una cosa y en la pregunta otra...
Tal sea el caso, te digo por adelantado que no puedes usar un procedimiento para retornar un valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te esta diciendo que el resultado query debe tener un destino o de lo contrario utiliza `PERFORM` en vez de `SELECT`, si tu función está retornando esos valores debe tener donde ponerlos para luego retornarlo o debe tener un `RETURN QUERY` por ejemplo:

```sql
create or replace function obtenerDatos (cliente character varying) returns table (nombre text, provincia text, pais text)
as 
$$

begin

return query SELECT NAME, STATE_ID, COUNTRY_ID FROM RES_PARTNER WHERE NAME = cliente;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Si lo que requieres es mostrarlos sin retornarlos puedes usar `RAISE NOTICE` y se lo asignas a una variable, por ejemplo:

```sql
create or replace function obtenerDatos2 (cliente character varying) returns void
as 
$$
declare 
resultado record ;
begin

 SELECT NAME, STATE_ID, COUNTRY_ID into resultado  FROM RES_PARTNER WHERE NAME = cliente;
 raise notice 'resultado: %', resultado;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: me funciono la primera opción la segunda me daba problemas me imagino que el void... muchísimas gracias